# .NET Garbage collector "race condition"

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Given the following scenario using C#:

```
Someclass lInstance = new SomeClass();
System.WeakReference lWInstance = new System.WeakReference(lInstance);

lInstance = null;

System.GC.Collect();
System.GC.SuppressFinalize(lWInstance.Target);
```

Imagine that when the SuppressFinalize executes, the GC thread is already inside Finalizer code of Someclass.

The question is what whould happen? I assume once the GC thread has entered the Finalizer supressing it has no effect.

Comment: What happened when you tried it? I'd guess that sometimes the finalizer is executed and sometimes not.

Comment: System.GC.Collect() is not guaranteed to do anything. It might just schedule a collection. My guess would be that once the finalization is started it won't be stopped unless it has some extra checks.

Comment: Why do you care? `SuppressFinalize` should be a performance optimization, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect `lWInstance.Target` to be null if the `lInstance` finalizer was executing.  I.e. that `WeakReference` would only return a reference to a valid, non-finalized target.

Comment: +1. It is an impossible race condition. If the SuppressFinalize method is handling the target, there is a non weak reference active -> ergo no finalization.

Comment: That will be true *unless the finalizer re-exposed the reference*.